# ViewModelProviders is outdated, what should be replaced?

Tags: android, kotlin

I use `ViewModelProviders`. But today, after updating the library, there were 30 messages. As I understand `ViewModelProviders` was no longer available and you need to replace it, I looked in the developer.google but did not understand what to replace ? My code:

```
inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> FragmentActivity.injectViewModel(factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory): T {
    return ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory)[T::class.java]
}

inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> Fragment.injectViewModel(factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory): T {
    return ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory)[T::class.java]
}
```

and can you explain why it's out of date ?

Comment: Can you specify what library and version you upgraded to (and from)?

Comment: @Pawel     implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$rootProject.lifecycleVersion"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$rootProject.lifecycleVersion"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$rootProject.lifecycleVersion"
 version '2.2.0-alpha02' to  2.2.0-rc02

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders.html#of(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment,%20androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory)):

> Use the `by viewModels()` Kotlin property delegate or [ViewModelProvider.ViewModelProvider(ViewModelStoreOwner, Factory)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider.html#ViewModelProvider(androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelStoreOwner,%20androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory)), passing in the fragment and factory.

So you can replace your extensions with:

```
inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> FragmentActivity.injectViewModel(factory:  ViewModelProvider.Factory): T {
    return ViewModelProvider(this, factory)[T::class.java]
}

inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> Fragment.injectViewModel(factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory): T {
    return ViewModelProvider(this, factory)[T::class.java]
}
```

And, as per the error message, you can instead use the Kotlin property extensions in the `fragment-ktx` and `activity-ktx` dependencies and remove your extension methods entirely.

Namely, [`by viewModels`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/package-summary#viewmodels) and [`by activityViewModels`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/package-summary#activityviewmodels) for Fragments:

```
// Retrieve the ViewModel associated with this Fragment
val viewModel: MyVewModel by viewModels { myFactory }

// Retrieve the ViewModel associated with the activity
val activityViewModel: MyVewModel by activityViewModels { myFactory }
```

Or, if you're accessing the ViewModel from your Activity itself, you'd use its [`by viewModels`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/activity/package-summary#viewmodels):

```
// In an Activity, you can retrieve a ViewModel scoped to the Activity
// by using viewModels
val viewModel: MyVewModel by viewModels { myFactory }
```

Comment: Do I need to set my binding's viewModel and lifecycleOwner using this approach? e.g.

`binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner`
        `binding.viewModel = viewModel`

I found this code in a tutorial for databinding in layouts but I'm not sure if it applies when using property delegates?

Answer (score 0):

you can use delegate if your ViewModel has some dependencies in this way...

```
protected val viewModel by activityViewModels<MainViewModel> {
    ViewModelFactory(ServicesRepo())
}
```